# How to pass string from windows phone app to windows phone runtime (winPRT)

Tags: c#, string, runtime, windows-phone

As I can't directly pass a string type data from managed code to runtime side as String^. How should I do it if I send a string. Thanks!

Comment: What's you use case here, as apps are sandboxed, and can only access the Operating System through the libraries provided, and not via p/Invoke

Answer (score 0):

Not possible via pInvoke in WP7...